# Pausing Node.js Readable Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, http, serial-port

I'm building a bar code scanning app using the node-serialport. Where I'm stuck is making a AJAX call to trigger a scan and then have Express server respond with the data from the readable stream.

Initialize Device:

```
// Open device port    
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = '/dev/cu.usbmodem1411';
var portObj = new SerialPort(port, (err) => {
 if(err) {
  console.log('Connection error ' + err);
 }
});

//Construct device object
var Scanner = {
  // Trigger Scan
  scan : () => {
    portObj.write(<scan cmd>), (err) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log('Error on scan' + err);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I've tried two approaches and neither produce the 'scan-read-respond' behavior I'm looking for.

First, I tried putting a event listener immediately following a scan, then using a callback in the listener to respond to the AJAX request. With this approach I get a 'Can't set headers after they are sent' error'. From what I understand Node is throwing this error  because res.send is being called multiple times.

First Approach -- Response as callback in listener:

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
 Scanner.scan(); //fire scanner
 portObj.on('data', (data) => {
  res.send(data); //'Can't set headers after they are sent' error'
 });
}
```

In the second approach, I store the scan data into a local variable ('scanned_data') and move the response outside the listener block. The problem with this approach is that res.send executes before the scanned data is captured in the local variable and so comes up as 'undefined'. Also intriguing is the scanned_data that is captured in the listener block seems to multiple with each scan.

Second Approach -- Response outside listener:

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  var scanned_data; //declare variable outside listener block
  Scanner.scan(); //trigger scan
  portObj.on('data', (data) => {
    scanned_data = data;
    console.log(scanned_data); //displays scanned data but data multiplies with each scan. (e.g. 3 triggers logs 'barcode_data barcode_data barcode_data')  
  });
  console.log(scanned_data); //undefined
  res.send(scanned_data);
}
```

I'm a front end developer but have gotten to learn a lot about Node trying to figure this out. Alas, I think I've come to a dead end at this point. I tinkered with the .pipe() command, and have a hunch that's where the solution lies, but wasn't able to zero in on a solution that works.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Have not tried node.js implementation of streams. Is requirement to use only node.js streams implementation? What is expected result.

Comment: Due to other constraints, I have to use node.js for stream implementation. The expected result is to be able to scan a barcode using a serial device (connected by node-serialport) and send that data as a response to a Ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

You should not make assumptions about what chunk of data you get in a `'data'` event. Expect one byte or many bytes. You need to know the underlying protocol being used to know when you have received a full "message" so you can stop listening for data. At that point you should then send a response to the HTTP request.

Comment: I think the data chunk in the readable stream consists of many bytes of data, which is why the data multiples with the number of scans. I was thinking of capping chunk size, but that may conflict with other features down the road that respond with bigger chunks. Any idea on how I can determine when the full message was received and make node stop listening for data?